# Disable OnBeforeUnload Event: How Do I Sent Javascript to a Cross Domain Iframe?

Tags: jquery, load, cross-domain, onbeforeunload

I want to accomplish something very simple.
I am referring to a website through an Iframe.

The iframe has a function with invokes "onBeforeUnload".
I want to DISABLE onbefore unload in the iframe, from my parent page.

I have figured out how to do this on SAME domain, and on same page. However, how can I do this for cross domain?

I will do anything it takes, no matter how complex, to make this work.

```
<iframe src="http://www.domain.com" width="100%" height="500" id="iframe"></iframe> 

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('#iframe').load( function() {
      alert('Load was performed.'); 
    document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.window.onbeforeunload=null; 
//NOTE: DOESN'T WORK CROSS DOMAIN! 
    });

    window.onbeforeunload=null  //Disables onbeforeunload event on THIS page so long as it is AFTER the original onbeforeunload event

    });

</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

making the innerhtml of containing div of iframe equal to empty string in onbeforeunload event of the main page will stop the alert.
using onbeforeunload of main page because there is no use of iframe while leaving the page.

Answer (score 0):

This simply isn't possible due to the Same Origin Policy unless you actually have your own code running in the iframe too.

In that case you could use easyXDM to do this - but if that was the case, you would just remove the handler directly right?

Comment: So there's NO possible way is what you're saying... not even some crazy workout script to override their onBeforeUnload, with my own in the parent page, for example? Anything...

Comment: Nope, it's not possible and would undermine the SOP if it was.

Comment: Alright, maybe you have the answer to another of my questions directly related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384885/how-to-trick-fool-an-iframe-to-thinking-its-the-top-element-in-dom