# How to Trick/Fool an Iframe to thinking its the TOP element in DOM

Tags: iframe, window

I've created this frame busting code, and now for fun, I want to bust it. 
This code appears inside an iframe page:

```
(function() {
 if (window!=top) {
//Bust out of iframe below:
 top.location.replace(location);
 }
})();
```

And it busts out of the iframe.

I do not want to alter this code at all, but I want a workaround code to put in the PARENT of this iframe, so that the iframe can't detect that its an iframe, thus invalidating this frame-busting code.

In other words, how do I make the iframe think that it IS the top window (meaning window==top)
Any workaround is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is not in itself possible, but there are a number of techniques for disabling the effect of common framebustin techniques - one of them can be read about [here](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/preventing-frame-busting-and-click-jacking-ui-redressing/).

It works by using the `onunloadevent` to 'cancel' the url-redirection by setting its location to a document returning a status code of 204.

Comment: `<pedantry>`: `204 No Content` is not an error, as errors are in the ranges of 4xx (client errors) and 5xx (server errors). It means "request succesful, No Content returned in response". http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2 `</pedantry>`

Comment: Haha, yeah, I know, I wasn't thinking :)

Comment: @Piskvor The W3C should actually add a `<pedantry>` tag. The default styling would be 60% opacity, and bold. Additionally, for some people, a `sarcastic` attribute could be added for screen readers! Honestly, I'm not sure why I spend my free time thinking about things like these...

Comment: coderrr.wordpress.com is no longer available.
The authors have deleted this site.

Comment: i know this is old but can any of you please elaborate on what the broken link (codeerr) had in it, so I can either search for it (like a title or summary text?) or look up something similar, and if it still is a valid thing?