# How to fool Iframe that it is top most window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I wonder, is there a way to override the iframe's window.top and window.parent such that from it's context the following is true

```
window === window.parent && window === window.top
```

The case is that the app that I want to embed in an iframe has many references to window.top, it stores objects and uses them to communicate back and forth with its own child iframes.

```
<iframe sandbox=""></iframe>
```

Without "allow-scripts" is not an option for me as any access to window.top throws and Error, while I want things to work pretty much as if the iframe was a top level window

Note:
I saw a similar question asked [How to Trick/Fool an Iframe to thinking its the TOP element in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384885/how-to-trick-fool-an-iframe-to-thinking-its-the-top-element-in-dom) but there while the same requirement, the actual problem - changing the top.location could be worked-around, this is why I guess the discussion was discontinued.

Comment: maybe naive, but would running `window.top=window;` in the iframe work?

Comment: Instead of trick the system, I would suggest, if you need the same code to be reused both with and without patent window, you replace them all with a variable and set that to the one you want at each time.

Comment: Found something that might help (let me know if it did): https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/656#issuecomment-57743689

Comment: Thanks for the tips
@dandavis setting window.top=window does not work as top is read only (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp) so it has no effect

Comment: @LGSon unfortunately modifying the code is not an option as it is a 3rd party app I have no control over. Also with the sandboxing options the iframe can still access the top most window with window.top, it disallows navigation from the iframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no you can not change a read-only property.

The more complex answer is that you could parse the other site through a proxy server and dynamically rewrite the JS. However I strongly expect that is more effort than it is worth and will likely break copyright laws at some point.

The question you should be asking is does the third-party want to be in your iFrame? If yes get them to fix their code, if no then you shouldn't be doing this.